# Xamarin: Any universal fix for ContentPage/StackLayout/AnyControl was not found

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Sometimes I get an error that Nothing in the Xaml-file is not found. This sometimes is fixed by restarting VS, Restore NuGetPackages, re-installing xamarin.forms nuget in combination with clean and removing obj-folders. But this is getting rather tiresome, and non of that works now.

> The type 'StackLayout' was not found. Verify that you are not missing
>   an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been
>   built.

Is there any universal fix on this or perhaps get a more accurate error message?

As I understand, this has been a problem for a long time with Xamarin forms

Seems to work reasonably well if you make sure the xaml-file´s Build Action is "Embedded resource" and not for example "Page". You can at least build, but you still get Intellisense-errors when you look at the pages

Many thanks in advance

Comment: An "Universal fix" should be to use latest and greatest tools.

Comment: Is there any documented fix in a new release or was that just a general tip?

Comment: Usually you get notified about new version of Visual Studio, Xamarin.Forms and etc. In addition to that you can always check https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/

Comment: This is a specific question, to a specific problem. Thanks anyway though ;)